# Rolling up items in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So let's say hypothetically I have a json array like this:

```
[{"country":"Argentina", "impressions":199}, 
{"country":"Peru", "impressions":100}, 
{"country":"Brazil", "impressions":500} 
{"country":"Argentina", "impressions":201}, 
{"country":"Peru", "impressions":504},]
```

and I want to use D3.js to create a table where each country is only listed once. Is there anything like "select distinct" in SQL for D3? I have all the code for the table already, and it generates a table that lays out my data exactly as it appears above, but I need the data rolled up.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me!

Comment: What happens to the differing `impressions` when you roll-up?  Do they get summed, averaged, maxed, etc...

Comment: @Mark I want them to get summed - currently nothing happens, because they're being laid out in the table as they appear in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

-- [d3.nest with a rollup](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) --

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.country;
  })
  .rollup(function(o){
    return d3.sum(o,function(d){
      return d.impressions;
    });
  })
  .entries(data);
```

Returns:

[image]

Full working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      "country": "Argentina",
      "impressions": 199
    }, {
      "country": "Peru",
      "impressions": 100
    }, {
      "country": "Brazil",
      "impressions": 500
    }, {
      "country": "Argentina",
      "impressions": 201
    }, {
      "country": "Peru",
      "impressions": 504
    }];

    var nested_data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.country;
      })
      .rollup(function(o){
        return d3.sum(o,function(d){
          return d.impressions;
        });
      })
      .entries(data);
      
    d3.select('body').html(JSON.stringify(nested_data));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```